# How to pass input to component from a promise in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular component rank-entry it takes an input variable server and then uses this variable in the template. This component is used by a rank-table component which is just a list of rank entries all representing different servers, the list of servers comes from rank-tables getServers() method which gets a promise from server service. This all works as expected.

Now I'm trying to make a more specific component, server-detail. This is accessed from the route /detail/:id and this component creates a table with only one row which should be a rank-entry for just the one server. I was expecting I would be able to use the getServer(id) method from server service, which would give server-detail a promised server and then the server can be given to the rank-entry component in the html but I'm getting an error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./RankEntryComponent class RankEntryComponent - inline template:4:4 caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.context.server.online')`

I think this might be because when the rank-entry component is created by the server-detail component the promise hasn't been resolved yet and the rank-entry doesn't have a server object?

Any help will be great thanks!

server-detail.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Server } from './utilities/Server';
import { ServerService } from './server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-detail',
  templateUrl: 'server-detail.component.html'
})
export class ServerDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private serverService: ServerService
  ){}

  @Input()
  server: Server;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      this.serverService.getServer(id).then(server => {this.server = server});
    })
  }

}
```

rank-entry.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Server } from './utilities/Server';

@Component({
  selector: 'tr[app-rank-entry]',
  templateUrl: './rank-entry.component.html'
})
export class RankEntryComponent {

  @Input()
  server: Server;

}
```

rank-entry.component.html

```
<th scope="row">{{server.rank}}</th>
<td>{{server.name}}</td>
<td><img [src]="this.server.img"/></td>
<td>{{server.currPlayers}}/{{server.maxPlayers}}</td>
<td *ngIf="server.online">Online</td><td *ngIf="!server.online">Offline</td>
```

server.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Server } from './utilities/Server';
import { SERVERS } from './utilities/mock-servers';

@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
  getServers(): Promise<Server[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(SERVERS);
  }

  getServer(id: number): Promise<Server> {
    return this.getServers().then(servers =>
      servers.find(server => server.id === id));
  }

}
```

And then my server-detail.component.html just creates the rank-entry component like so: `<tr app-rank-entry [server]="server"></tr>`

I'm only new to Angular 2 so I don't really know anything more than the heroes tutorial at the moment, though through some googling I've seen things such as the Elvis operator ? and the async pipe but neither of these work!

Comment: i think this `<div *ng-if='server'> rank-entry.component.html </div>`will solve the error.